# Efficient way of looping in PHP

Tags: php

I am a beginner for PHP and also for coding. I have the following piece of code which increments the month.

```
 if (isset($_REQUEST['Receipts'])) {
   $months = array( " 31 Jan 2000"," 28 Feb 2000"," 31 Mar 2000","30 Apr 2000","31 May 2000",
                    "30 Jun 2000","31 Jul 2000"," 31 Aug 2000","30 Sep 2000","31 Oct 2000",
                    "30 Nov 2000","31 Dec 2000");
   foreach ($months as $month){
     $params['Date'] = '31 Jan 2000';
      $response = $Auth->request('GET', $Auth->url('Receipts/Travel', 'core'), $params);
      if ($Auth->response['code'] == 200) {
       $receipt = $Auth->parseResponse($OAuth->response['response'], $Auth->response['format']);
       pr($receipt->Receipts);
      } 
     else 
     {
      outputError($Auth);
     }
   }
```

I have used the very basic example of storing the month values in array and looping it. I wanted to know how to increment the month values instead of storing it directly in array because I need to edit the code for other years which is not feasible. Could any body help on this?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't actually appear that you are doing anything with the array values in the loop. While you are looping through the array, you have a hardcoded date value `$params['Date'] = '31 Jan 2000';`. It appears that you are requesting the same data everytime for the duration of the length of the array `$months` (i.e. you're looping `count($months)` times, but using the same `$params['Date']` value for each `GET` request).

Comment: Use an associative array that maps month names to the number of days in the month. Then it will work for any year (except you have to deal with February specially in leap years).

Comment: You can just use numbers for the months and use php's date functions to get the names and the last day of a given month in a given year and format it how you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['Receipts'])) {
  $months = array( "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");
  $year=2000;
  foreach ($months as $i=>$month) {
    // Because arrays are 0-indexed, and cal_days_in_month takes the month number 1-indexed
    $monthNumber=$i+1;
    $numberOfDaysInMonth=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $monthNumber, $year);
    $params['Date'] = "$numberOfDaysInMonth $month $year";
    $response = $Auth->request('GET', $Auth->url('Receipts/Travel', 'core'), $params);
    if ($Auth->response['code'] == 200) {
      $receipt = $Auth->parseResponse($OAuth->response['response'], $Auth->response['format']);
      pr($receipt->Receipts);
    } else {
      outputError($Auth);
    }
  }


?>
```

---

On a side note, i think you could benefit from looking at PHPs DateTime() class:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_date.asp

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $time = strtotime("last day of 2000-$i-01");
    $date = date('j M Y');
    ... your other stuff here...
}
```

The strtotime() calculates the last day of that month, returns it as a timestamp of 12:00:00am that day (e.g. 2014-12-31 00:00:00), which then gets formatted into your friendly "31 Dec 2000".

If you need more years, then just add another loop around all of this and generate/retrieve your year values that way.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use deticated class, exactly designed for this kind of task - [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php)

```
$year = '2050';
$iterator = new DatePeriod("R11/$year-01-01T00:00:00Z/P1M");
foreach ($iterator AS $month) {
    $month->modify('last day of this month');
    var_dump($month);
}
```

Notice how this allows you to:

- Iterate over any date / time period only with couple of lines of code
- Handle leap years
- Handle dates after year 2038

*"R11/2050-01-01T00:00:00Z/P1M"* is an ISO 8601 string where:

- R11 - indicates number of iterations
- 2050-01-01 - date where iteration starts
- T00:00:00 - time where iteration starts
- Z - UTC 0 offset
- P1M - "period plus one month(s)" - tells to iterate plus one month at a time

Inside the foreach loop we can just use *modify('last day of this month')* in order to set date to the last day of current month. And there you have it - this way you get DateTime object, representing last day of month, for every month in year, in ascending order. To convert those objects to strings check out DateTime [format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.